How do I get sorted results from a SQLite3 table in Python with parameters included
I have a program running that pulls information from a SQLite3 db when searched for using dropdown menus. I'm trying to use the ORDER BY function on the shown informaiton but keep getting typeerrors. The function relies on a mix of SQL and Python to allow for the search parameters from the dropdown menus and without the ORDER BY statement, it works fine, I just need it to order the results tto make it easier to read.
I've created tables and db already, this is a small section of the function call that I can't seem to find where to add the ORDER BY statement
eightspdSQL = '''SELECT cassettes_8spd.brand, cassettes_8spd.model, cassettes_8spd.partNumber, cassettes_8spd.speed, cassettes_8spd.ratio, distributor_table.distributor_name, cassettes_8spd.rrp, distributor_table.distributor_link_url 
        FROM cassettes_8spd, distributor_table WHERE cassettes_8spd.distributor_id = distributor_table.distributor_id '''

def get_speed_8spd(speed: int):
    connect = connect_database()
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    print(speed)
    result = cursor.execute(eightspdSQL + "AND speed=?", [speed] + "ORDER BY brand ASC")

    rows = result.fetchall()
    connect.close()
    return response(rows)

I expected to be able to mix Python and SQL in result = cursor.execute(eightspdSQL + "AND speed=?", [speed]) + "ORDER BY brand ASC") but it keeps throwing an error.

It would probably help to know what the error actually was. Your SQL looks like a blend of parameterized and non-parameterized SQL. Pick one strategy or the other.

You might try cursor.execute(eightspdSQL + " AND speed=? ORDER BY brand ASC", (speed))

could you provide an [mre] clarifying exactly which SQL module you're using (i.e., where is connect_database() coming from) and the traceback of the error?

Try incorporating ORDER BY into the main SQL string eightspdSQL.
cassettes_8spd.speed = ? ORDER BY cassettes_8spd.brand ASC

try doing this after from casesettes_8spd distributor table

The problem is that you are wrapping the speed value in [] to make a list, when you should just be passing the int at the end of the query as a parameter instead of using string concatenation or f-strings.
Using concatenation or f-strings opens you to a possible SQL injection attack.
result = cursor.execute(eightspdSQL + "AND speed=? ORDER BY brand ASC", speed)


Are you sure about that?  I thought the parameter values always had to be in a list/tuple, even if it's only one item, to accommodate the case when the query has more than one ? placeholder.

@John Gordon,  Well, the OP didn't include what package he is using as he didn't provide an [mre], or the actual error message, but it would fit with the TypeError he's getting.   Maybe I've been spoiled by a good SQLAlchemy wrapper that was handling more parsing than I realized, as it expects execute(sql, *args, **kwargs) and allows for using either ? or named placeholders.
